# Wordpress WP Query + Custom Post + Custom Fields + Order By Composto

Tags: php, wordpress

Boa tarde, procurei bastante sobre isso, resumindo:
Preciso de uma query que traga a postagem (custom post documentos,  (título e data de publicação), além do custom_post (Documento que é um arquivo, Unidade que é um Select e Tipo que é outro Select)

Até o momento consegui este código, mas não está funcionando:

```
    $args = array (
        'post_type'              => array( 'documentos' ),
        'post_status'            => array( 'publish' ),
        'nopaging'               => true,
        'orderby'        => array( 'unidade' => 'ASC', 'tipo' => 'ASC', 'post_date' => 'DESC' )
        'meta_key' => 'unidade'
    );

    $services = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ( $services->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $services->have_posts() ) {
            $services->the_post();
            // do something
        }
    } else {
        // no posts found
    }

// Restore original Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Esta query não está funcionando ainda... Pesquisei bastante, mas tem algum detalhe que deixei passar...

- Ninguém consegue ajudar?

**obs.: O erro que está dando é o 500, estou fazendo em uma página separada**